# How do I set an array equal to a variable which stores console.next();?

Tags: java

```
 String typed=console.next();
 String[] arrayNum = new String[0];
 arrayNum=typed;
```

how do I do the last line? I keep getting an error "cannot convert from String to []String". I want to fill an array with the characters typed from the console.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are not yet understand an array either.

typeOfArray[] arrayName = new typeOfArray[numberOfElements];

You can read more here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm

For example:

1. `String[] arrayString = new String[10];`
   -- 10 elements with the type of String.
2. `int[] arrayInt = new int[2];`
   -- 2 elements with the type of integer.
   And so on.

And there is ArrayList:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com//java/util/java_util_arraylist.htm

Basically, array list acts like an array. By default, it will start with 10 elements, and if you keep pushing more data in, the array list will automatically increase by 10 more.

> ArrayList newArray = new ArrayList(1000);

This is an example of an ArrayList with a 1000 elements.

To push data in, you use add() --

> newArray.add("A String");

To get data out, you use get() --

> newArray.get(0);

-- 0 is the index number of where you store your data (result for this one will return "A String").

For more example, read the link above.

Comment: Great answer, but it's generally considered better form not to rely on linked information - whatever is necessary for understanding should be summarized, and the link can serve as backup. (This ensures that the SO post is self contained, and can't succumb to link rot.)

Comment: Thanks for the head up. I just think that if I include more info about Array List, @Picklejar 75 will confuse by the concept. I believe that is the reason why I should provide the link instead.

I will keep your advice in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Java is **strongly typed language**,   meaning once you declare variable as certain type you can use it only as the defined type.
In your case you define

> String typed=console.next();

The variable typed holds the data returned by console.text(), which **is of type String**, so this line is perfectly fine.

Next you define new variable

> String[] arrayNum = new String[0];

The variable arrayNum **is of type String[]**, this is completely different type of data for the java compiler.
So naturally when you try to store String in String[] you get an error, this will happen for every two different kinds of data.

One solution for you, if you really need the console line as array is using

> String.toCharArray();

Like this

`String typed=console.next();
 char[] arrayNum = typed.toCharArray();`

String is actually an char[] ( array of characters ), but the class String serves as a wrapper around this array, and provides some very useful methods for manipulating it.
So now you arrayNum variable hold the characters of you input as array of symbols.

My advice is to not use array in this case, since the String class works fine in most cases.